# Using text input by a user to reference a variable

Tags: javascript, html

first time I believe I have posted in stackoverflow and I hope I can explain what I would like to try and accomplish.

To try and phrase my question the most concisely, is there a way I can have a user input a string of words into a form in **HTML**, then use **Javascript** to check to see if any of those words match a variable that is already declared and then reference that variable so that I can use the value that is saved there?

For example we will have var feet = 12 declared, and a user inputs the word "feet" into a text field.  I want to be able to take the user input and use it to reference the variable for later purposes in the code.

Hopefully explains my scenario well enough and someone can offer some advice

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is a global variable, you can use `window[varname]` to get the value of the variable whose name is in `varname`.

Do you really need to allow the user to access any random Javascript variable? If not, a better approach would be to use an object to hold the data you want to allow the user to access.  E.g.

```
var units = {
  feet: 12,
  inches: 1,
  ...
}

var conversion_factor = units[user_input];
```

Comment: I guess it isn't really any "random" javascript variable since I only need for them to access a set of variables that I have defined already.  I am sure my code is clunky, but I am pulling apart a phrase that is input by the user to try and solve a basic question of "How many (imperial units) are in # (metric units)".  I have to apologize in advance, my object oriented coding is weak at best.

Comment: That's a perfect use for a table in an object. See my updated answer.

Comment: Just to confirm, a users input could be saved to your "user_input" variable and units[user_input] will retrieve the value of the declared objects that were created in units if it matches any of them?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Objects in Javascript can be used like associative arrays in PHP, hashes in Perl, and dictionaries in Python.

Comment: Alrighty!  I'll give it a whirl.  I like this a lot more than the bajillion conditional statements I would have done as a last ditch solution.